# Code first DbContext usage

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, dbcontext

I have been trying to work with Entity Framework's Code First. I wrote the below line of code

```
DbContext _context = new  DbContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString);
```

However on execution, the connection remains closed. Is there something wrong with this code??

I have created a generic repository class using the DBContext shown below

```
public class GenericRepository<T> where T:class
  {   

public DbContext _context = new DbContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString);

private DbSet<T> _dbset;

public DbSet<T> Dbset
{

    set { _dbset = _context.Set<T>(); }
    get { return _dbset; }

}

public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
{

    return Dbset;
}  
}
```

and I then call this class on the page load event, where Teacher is an entity class which maps to a table in the database

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GenericRepository<Teacher> studentrepository = new GenericRepository<Teacher>();
    rptSchoolData.DataSource = studentrepository.GetAll().ToList();
    rptSchoolData.DataBind();
}
```

but the connection remains closed and there is also an InvalidOperation Exception in the ServerVersion of the context object.

Am I missing something??

Comment: You need to create your own context class that inherits from DbContext and defines your entity collections.

Comment: My database already exists with tables. Which is what I have specified in my connection string which I have passed into the DbContext object. Would I still need a class which inherits from it?

Comment: @RAHUL - yes, you need to define a class which has `DbSet`s for each of the tables in your database that you want mapped in that context.

Comment: You may want to use EF Power Tools - it contains the reverse engineer option which can create a code first model based on your database. You don't also have to read your config to provide the connection string. You can use "name={connection string name}" convention - in your case "name=con" should work.

Comment: I have edited my post above to show the exact scenario....please have a look at it.

Comment: The inner exception I get in the DBContext object when i debug it is "ServerVersion: InvalidOperationException. The connection is closed."

Comment: The Database and the connection string are all fine. Don't know why this occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This property

```
public DbSet<T> Dbset
{
    set { _dbset = _context.Set<T>(); }
    get { return _dbset; }
}
```

has a heavy smell to it. A setter that does nothing with `value` is an anti pattern big time. Do you expect to set the `DbSet` after creating a `GenericRepository`?

I don't understand that your code even works because you never initialize `_dbset`, it should throw a null object reference exception.

The `_dbset` and `DbSet` shouldn't be there in the first place. `GetAll` should return `_context.Set<T>()`. EF should open and close the connection all by itself. Maybe the fact that you don't initialize the DbSet causes a connection never to open, causing problems in other pieces of code not revealed here.

Comment: Thank you Gert for that....I initialized _dbset in the getter and it took care of that problem. However i now have another issue. I get the exception "The entity type Teacher is not part of the model in the current context". I forgot to mention that I am using an existing database, with values and am using code first for data   operations on it. Am I forgetting anything?

Comment: You better make a new question for that. It's a different issue and it requires code of your class model and mappings. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477420/code-first-generic-repository-with-existing-database-tables                                                        I have created a new question at the above link. Please look into it.